# RegionDifference imperfection

Tags: regions, syntax, geometry, mesh

Consider the following two regions:

```
Vol1 = Region@Cylinder[{{0, 0, -26.5}, {0, 0, 26.5}}, 11.3];
Vol2 = Region@
   RegionProduct[
    Annulus[{1.7, 1.8}, {0.001, 20}, {ArcSin[-(28.7/(2*20))] + Pi/2, 
      ArcSin[28.7/(2*20)] + Pi/2}], Line[{{-26.5}, {26.5}}]];
```

I would like to get their difference:

```
reg3=RegionDifference[Vol2,Vol2]
```

However, the resulting region is not accurate:

[image]

Namely, the inner radius does not look like a circle. Could you please tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Rationalize`ing the two volumes before taking the region difference fixes the issue:

```
RegionDifference[Rationalize @ Vol2, Rationalize @ Vol1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You are using [`Region`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Region.html) unnecessarily in some instances.

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

reg1 = Cylinder[{{0, 0, -26.5}, {0, 0, 26.5}}, 11.3];
reg2 = RegionProduct[
   Annulus[{1.7, 1.8}, {0.001, 20}, {ArcSin[-(28.7/(2*20))] + Pi/2, 
     ArcSin[28.7/(2*20)] + Pi/2}], Line[{{-26.5}, {26.5}}]];
```

These are valid regions without using `Region`

```
RegionQ /@ {reg1, reg2}

(* {True, True} *)
```

As kglr pointed out, using exact values fixes the issue.

```
reg3 = RegionDifference[reg2, reg1] // Rationalize;

RegionQ@reg3

(* True *)

Region[reg3]
```

[image]